# Causing a tooltip to popup and fade out on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tooltip function and I am new to javascript:

```
$( function()
{
    var targets = $( '[rel~=tooltip]' ),
        target  = false,
        tooltip = false,
        title   = false;
    targets.bind( 'click', function()
    {
        target  = $( this );
        tip = target.attr('title');
        tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

        if( !tip || tip == '' )
            return false;

        target.removeAttr( 'title' );
        tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
               .html( tip )
               .appendTo( 'body' );

        var init_tooltip = function()
        {
            if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
            else
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

            var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
                pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;

            if( pos_left < 0 )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );

            if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );

            if( pos_top < 0 )
            {
                var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
                tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );

            tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
                   .animate({ top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50);
            tooltip.fadeOut(6000);
        };

        init_tooltip();
        $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );
    });
});
```

Currently, when the element is clicked it shows, and then fades out. This is the desired behavior. However, you can only click the option once a page reload. How can I make it where the function will show the tooltip and fate out on each click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just taking a quick look at your code you are removing the title `target.removeAttr( 'title' )`. So the next time you click there is no title to display.